# How do I specify type parameter in pattern matching for phantom type

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, type-parameter

Let's say I have this:

```
data PT1
data PT2
data DT1 a = DT1 { field :: Int }

newtype DT2 a = DT2 (DT1 a)

f :: Int -> DT2 a -> Int
f x (DT2 (DT1 PT1 field)) = 5 -- How do I specify the type param?
f x (DT2 (DT1 PT2 field)) = 7 -- How do I specify the type param?
```

The question is there in comments. The above doesn't compile. I want to pattern match differently based on the type parameter. How do I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pattern match on the type. What you can do is use a typeclass like this:

```
class Effable t where
  f :: Int -> t -> Int

instance Effable (DT2 PT1) where
  f x (DT2 _) = 5

instance Effable (DT2 PT2) where
  f x (DT2 _) = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a pattern match provide evidence for a type parameter, you can use GADTs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data PT1
data PT2

data Tag a where
    PT1 :: Tag PT1
    PT2 :: Tag PT2

data DT1 a = DT1 { tag :: Tag a, field :: Int }

newtype DT2 a = DT2 (DT1 a)

f :: Int -> DT2 a -> Int
f x (DT2 (DT1 PT1 field)) = 5
f x (DT2 (DT1 PT2 field)) = 7
```

But now the type is no longer a phantom type - you're carrying around a run-time tag.

I'm not sure what advantage this has over what @sepp2k suggested, or even if this would be useful. It just gives you what you asked for with minal modification to your example code :-)